# Running different excel macros from one vbscript at different hours

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, macros, windows-task-scheduler

I want to use **vbs** file - which will fire **different macros** at **different hours**. I was thinking about putting it in the **windows startup programs** folder

The point is I want this vbs to fire each of these macros in different hours (Let's assume I will have machine on long enough).

I tried to make separate vbs files for each macro and launch it with windows scheduler. It works, but i dont like this solution and I want to learn smth. To be clear what i want to achieve is:

> Launching Computer at 12 -> VBScript is launching at windows start,
>   then it fires:
>
> Macro a at 13, and update it on 13.15
>
> Macro b at 15
>
> then Macro c at 16 using data from Macro b, and then closing itself
>   (both macro and vbs).

OFC i will launch computer and close it manually :)

Thanks,
Dawid

Comment: Windows Scheduler is probably the best option, honestly. Better not to have some process constantly running if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the timer function which returns the number of seconds since midnight.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264416.aspx

To ensure it's not checking every second try the Wait function as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx

I'm still new, so hopefully someone else will expand on this for you, but it should be a good starting point.